# Changing default icon theme so that current one follows the new default

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, default, gnome-tweaks

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, in the Tweak Tool it says Adwaita is the default icon set.

I am using the Nordic darker theme and I want to get the folder icons from the Yaru icon set. But when I set Nordic darker as the icon theme, the icons for folders are used from Adwaita (Default).

That's why I want to make Yaru the default icon set. Is there any way I can make Yaru the default icon set or achieve my goal by some other means?

Comment: Adwaita (Default) - - > Yaru ( Default) Like this?? out of the box Yaru is the icon theme rite??

Comment: Yes, is there a way to make Adwaita (Default) - - > Yaru ( Default) Like this ??

Comment: requires more workout.. do you have any strong reason..

Comment: Actually i am using Nordic darker theme and i want Nordic folders with the Yaru icon set but when i set Nordic folders as icons set the the icon except folders are used from Adwaita(Default). That's why i am trying to make Yaru as default.

Comment: now it seems it is easier to edit some files with few lines are enough.. your actual question is possible but requires editing core files.. let me understand your above comment clearly and the will see existing posts..

Comment: sorry for my bad english, in one sentence how can i use Yaru icon theme with Nordic folder icons ? hope that helps.

Comment: is was solved by editing /usr/share/icons/nordic-darker/index.theme file.  just replace the "inheritance=......"  line with this line " Inherits=Yaru" .

Comment: yes thats what my idea too.. write it as answer..

Comment: This is a typical example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You should always mention your *actual problem* instead of asking about issues regarding your *attempted solution*. Please **[edit]** your question and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The goal was achieved by editing the `/usr/share/icons/nordic-darker/index.theme` file. Just replace the

```
inheritance=...
```

line with the line

```
Inherits=Yaru
```

(solution based on a [comment by the OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253083/changing-default-theme#comment2116115_1253083))